# Cooperative Counting

Tags: game, king-of-the-hill

### Final results

## 1st place goes to *Follow*!

Honourable mentions to **The diff predictor** (2nd), and **Simple Killer**, **Low Blow** and **High to Low** (joint 3rd).

Other winners:

#### (score competition) 1st - Simple Killer

Honourable mentions: **The diff predictor** and **Naiive**.

#### (wins competition) 1st - Crab

Honourable mentions: **Follow** and **High to Low**.

Full results:

```
By score:
1: Simple Killer with 1208099 points
2: The diff predictor with 1053087 points
3: Naiive with 1051505 points
4: Follow with 905731 points
5: The dedicated counter with 769680 points
6: The Desperate Fighter with 769663 points
7: Low Blow with 763357 points
8: High to Low with 734011 points
9: Naughty or Nice? with 714912 points
10: Grim Trigger with 713702 points
11: Tit for tat with 713067 points
12: The primitive looker with 621028 points
13: Hard-coded with 428934 points
14: Zoidberg with 395702 points
15: FunnyNumber with 335179 points
16: Random with 329023 points
17: Shortcut with 257190 points
18: Meandian with 223051 points
19: Hawk with 47608 points
20: Crab with 14852 points

By wins:
1: Crab with avg. 19.0/19 wins
2: Follow with avg. 17.1/19 wins
3: High to Low with avg. 15.8/19 wins
4: Low Blow with avg. 14.9/19 wins
5: The diff predictor with avg. 14.1/19 wins
6: Meandian with avg. 13.7/19 wins
7: Hawk with avg. 13.0/19 wins
8: Hard-coded with avg. 11.7/19 wins
9: Naughty or Nice? with avg. 11.0/19 wins
10: Simple Killer with avg. 10.4/19 wins
11: The primitive looker with avg. 8.0/19 wins
12: Naiive with avg. 6.6/19 wins
13: Zoidberg with avg. 6.3/19 wins
14: Shortcut with avg. 5.0/19 wins
14: Grim Trigger with avg. 5.0/19 wins
16: FunnyNumber with avg. 4.0/19 wins
17: Random with avg. 3.0/19 wins
18: Tit for tat with avg. 1.0/19 wins
19: The dedicated counter with avg. 0.0/19 wins
19: The Desperate Fighter with avg. 0.0/19 wins

Combined leaderboard (fewer pts = better):
1: Follow  (6 pts)
2: The diff predictor  (7 pts)
3: Simple Killer  (11 pts)
3: Low Blow  (11 pts)
3: High to Low  (11 pts)
6: Naiive  (15 pts)
7: Naughty or Nice?  (18 pts)
8: Hard-coded  (21 pts)
8: Crab  (21 pts)
10: The primitive looker  (23 pts)
11: The dedicated counter  (24 pts)
11: Grim Trigger  (24 pts)
11: Meandian  (24 pts)
14: The Desperate Fighter  (25 pts)
15: Hawk  (26 pts)
16: Zoidberg  (27 pts)
17: Tit for tat  (29 pts)
18: FunnyNumber  (31 pts)
18: Shortcut  (31 pts)
20: Random  (33 pts)
```

---

## Cooperative Counting - Python 3 KOTH

Have you ever tried to count to 100 in an online forum or comment thread? It normally goes something like:

```
1
>2
>>3
>>>4
>>>>69 xD xD
```

the point being that someone will always try to ruin the fun.

## The game

This is a bit like the counting example above, except to make sure that neither player has an advantage
from going first, each player will count at the same time as the other.

Your bot will be pitted against another bot. Your goal? Cooperatively count to 100.

Each round, your bot decides how far it is willing to cooperatively count with its opponent.

### Possible outcomes

**One player stops counting before the other**

The player who stopped counting first is awarded twice as many points as the value they counted up to. The other player gains no points.

**Both you and your opponent stop counting at the same time**

Neither of you gain any points.

**Both you and your opponent count all the way to 100**

Each player gains 100 points.

### Example

- Player 1: decides to count to 80
- Player 2: decides to count to 30

Player 2 gets 60 points, player 1 gets 0 points.

---

In another round:

- Player 1: decides to count to 57
- Player 2: decides to count to 57

Neither player gets points.

---

In yet another round:

- Player 1: decides to count to 100
- Player 2: decides to count to 100

Each player gets 100 points.

## Overall game flow

Your bot will be matched against other bots. It will play some number of rounds in a row, `n`, against the same bot.
`n` will be somewhere in the range of 100 - 1000. This allows your bot to adapt to the other bot's strategy.

## Winning the KOTH

Each bot will have a go against each other bot. Your bot can win in three categories:

- **Score:** the total scores will be summed and the bot with the most points at the end will win.
- **Wins:** a 'win' is counted for the bot with the highest score after the `n` rounds have been played.
- **Overall:** both the other categories combined

## Technical details

Write a function in Python 3 with this signature:

```py
def strategy(last_results: list[tuple[int, bool]]) -> int
```

- `strategy` is called once at the beginning of each round.

  - `last_results` is a list of previous results against the same opponent. Each item in the list is the result of a round in the form `(value reached, won)`, where `won` denotes whether the player
    won or not. If the player won through cooperation, this will be `True`.
  - e.g.: if you lose your first round because your opponent stops counting at 79, `last_results` looks like `[(79, False)]` at the start of round 2. If you then win round 2 by stopping counting at 34, `last_results` will look like `[(79, False), (34, True)]` at the start of round 3.
  - `strategy` should return the value at which the bot will stop counting. `1` stops counting immediately, `100` is an agreement to count cooperatively with the other bot all the way to the end, and e.g. `47` will stop counting when the value is `47`, earning the bot 84 points.

### Example bot

'Naiive' counts up to one before the number that was reached last round if it lost, otherwise it counts up to and including the number it won on.

```py
def strategy(last_games):
    if len(last_games) == 0:
        return 100
    
    # Count up to one before the last number that was counted if we lost,
    # otherwise just up to the last number that was counted.
    if last_games[-1][1]:
        return last_games[-1][0]
    else:
        return max(1, last_games[-1][0] - 1)
```

### Legacy format (don't use)

**I've decided on a simpler format since the last one was causing confusion. Here is the old one for reference purposes. New submissions should be in the new format. Submissions using the legacy format do not need to update their submission.**

```py
# Don't use this, see above
def strategy(last_results: list[tuple[int, bool]]) -> tuple:
    pass

def turn(current_value: int, *args) -> bool:
    pass
```

## Rules

- No cheating by interfering directly with your opponent (through global variables etc.).
- Your function should be relatively quick to execute - the quicker it is, the better.
- You *may* submit multiple entries.
- Submissions close a week from the start of this post, at 2021-04-17 11:00 UTC

## Controller, sandbox, arena

**The controller is available at https://github.com/jthistle/KOTH-counting.**

A couple of example bots are provided along with it to demonstrate how to use it.

`sandbox.py` provides a place to try out your bot against others and debug it.

`arena.py` is what I'll be using to calculate final scores. It pits each bot against each other bot.

Comment: As someone who has run quite a few KotHs, this is probably the best one I've ever seen with such a simple premise. Looks like I'll be learning Python now :p

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms thank you! Apologies for restricting it to Python, but I find cross-process programming tricky

Comment: @jumbot Definitely better to keep it to one language, I needed an excuse to practice other languages anyway :p

Comment: I made [this](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/eba00331eaba5e98f28bcbc1e9a989fe) script to make updating the controller with new bots a bit easier. It automatically fetches the new bots with the API and puts them in the `contestants` folder, then adds them to `arena.py`. If you notice any weird bugs let me know, this is probably my first time writing anything serious in Python :p

Comment: Isn't 'get one point ahead, then completely refuse to count' the perfect strategy? And *any* strategy that counts properly at least once loses to Crab, so the only strategy that doesn't lose to Crab is Crab.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122876/discussion-on-question-by-jumbot-cooperative-counting).

Comment: Given that multiple bots use randomness, it might be better to run multiple contests and use the average of the results. Low Blow has a small chance of coming 3rd in points, and normally gets 13/14 wins, but due to the randomness, it can change in one-off contests

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing this is true. I'll see what I can do about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Follow

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    n = len(last_results)
    if n == 0: return 100
    if all(i == (1,False) for i in last_results): return 2 # nice to the crab
    a,b = last_results[-1]
    if n == 1:
        if b: return 100
        return 1+int(.97*(a-1))
    c,d = last_results[-2]
    if n >= 99 and a == 100: return 99
    if b and d: # won previous two rounds
        if (a+1,False) not in last_results:
            return min(100,a+1)
        return a
    else:
        a,c = sorted((a,c))
        return max(1,a*a//c-1)
```

Starts out by counting to 100. After round 99, if it previously counted to 100, it will only count to 99 (the reasoning is that it would otherwise tie with everything else that keeps counting to 100). If it detects the crab, it's nice (because it doesn't matter anyways). If it lost the previous round, then it counts lower than whatever won in the previous round (between 1 to 3 less). If it won the previous round, then it counts one further if it hasn't lost by counting that far before.

Edit: Made it use the ratio between the previous two moves to decide what to count to, made it only start increasing if it won the previous two rounds, and figured out a better way to check for the crab

Comment: Congrats! You won :)

Answer (score 17):

## Crab

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    return 1
```

Crab *always* stops counting, because it'd rather not get points than have the other bot beat it. It is because of Crab that we can't have nice things.

Comment: And I thought shortcut was cynical

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Like programmer, like bot, I guess :P. I'll make a slightly better designed one soon to make up for the atrocity that is Crab.

Comment: I love this :))

Answer (score 12):

## Low Blow

```python
import random
import statistics

def strategy(last_results):
        scores = list(map(lambda a: a[0], last_results))
        if not scores: return 99

        if len(scores) > 420 and scores[:3] == [69, 68, 68]:
                return 67

        decrements = [50, 69, 48]

        if all(score == 1 for score in scores): return 1

        for decrement in decrements:
                mold = [decrement]
                for _ in scores[1:]: mold.append(decrement - 1)
                if scores == mold:
                        return decrement - 1

        if scores[0] == 65:
                if scores[-1] == 1: return 1
                return random.randint(1, 48)

        if scores == [98]:
                return 97

        if len(scores) == 1 and scores[0] < 48:
                return scores[0]

        if last_results[:2] == [(99, True), (99, False)]:
                return max(scores[-1] - 1, 1)

        if scores[:2] == [47, 31]    : return max(min(50, int(sum(scores) / (len(scores) * 1.5))) - 1, 1)
        if scores[:2] == [99, 97]    : return max(scores[-1] - 3, 1)
        if scores[:2] == [99, 98]    : return max(scores[-1] - 2, 1)
        if scores[:3] == [99, 99, 98]: return max(scores[-1] - 1, 1)

        if scores[:2] == [98, 97]    :
                htl_losses = [result[0] for result in last_results if result[1]]
                return max(min(htl_losses) - len(htl_losses) - 2, 1)

        if len(scores) > 1 and scores[0] == scores[1] != 99:
                mean = round(statistics.mean(scores))
                median = round(statistics.median(sorted(scores)))

                if mean == median:
                        return max(mean - 1, 1)
                return max(abs(median - mean) - 1, 1)

        if scores[-1] == 1:
                return 1

        if len(scores) <= 3: return 99

        deltas = [scores[~0] - scores[~1], scores[~1] - scores[~2]]
        if any(deltas): return random.randint(37, 50)

        return 99
```

Low Blow's strategy is somewhat "kamikaze". It aims to reduce the opposition bot's score as much as possible, even if that means that Low Blow scores fewer points. However, it does aim to capitalise on points against specific bots where possible.

It does this by identifying the bot it's against, then playing their own strategy against them, but one lower than what they'd return. Either, the values are constant and Low Blow collects a bunch of points, or the values eventually reach 1, at which point Low Blow will likely\${}^*\$ have more points and neither bot will get more

\${}^*\$"Likely" because of randomness from Hard-coded

Comment: Nice one! Can confirm that low blow is leagues ahead...

Comment: Nice. Will your program still win against me (on average) after my edit?

Answer (score 8):

## The dedicated counter

Updated to use the new format (slight performance gain, which adds up):

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    return 100
```

Original:

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    return ()

def turn(current_value, *args):
    return True
```

No matter what the opponent does, this bot will always count up. With determination it keeps going in the face of potential trolls. I'll be writing a more thought out bot once I can see the examples.

Comment: `strategy` needs to return a tuple. (in this case it will always be empty though)

Comment: i.e., change `pass` to `return ()`. But thank you for the submission!

Comment: @jumbot I've changed the return format - I wasn't sure how it should work. Nice koth BTW.

Answer (score 8):

## Simple Killer

```
def strategy(last_results):
    if not len(last_results):
        return 100
    if len(last_results) == 999 and last_results[-1][0] == 100:
        return 99
    last_move = last_results[-1]
    if last_move in last_results[:-1]:
        pos = last_results.index(last_move)
        if last_results[pos + 1][1]:
            return last_results[pos + 1][0]
        return max(last_results[pos + 1][0] - 1, 1)
    return 100
```

Simple Killer targets a certain class of bot: those who consider only the most recent move (or don't look at the past).  By determining exactly how the opposing bot typically reacts, Simple Killer is able to slowly figure out the optimal move in any given circumstance.

It either loses by a narrow margin, wins by a huge margin, or plays nice (if the other bot is happy to just sit at 100).

Comment: This is probably the smartest answer that isn't just a hard-coded bot... nice one!

Answer (score 6):

## The primitive looker

This is a bot which learns from its previous rounds.

New version:

```
def strategy(last_results):
    if not last_results:
        return 100
    if any(not x[1] for x in last_results):
        if last_results[-1][0] - 2 > 0:
            return last_results[-1][0] - 2
        return 100
    return 99
```

Legacy version:

```
import random

def strategy(last_results):
    try:
        return (last_results, )
    except:
        return ([], )

def turn(current_value, res):
    v = 99
    m = 2
    g = True
    for i in res:
        if not i[1]:
            g = False
            break
        
    if res == []:
        c = True
    else:
        if res[-1][1] and g:
            if current_value == v:
                c = False
            else:
                c = True
        else:
            if current_value == res[-1][0] - m:
                c = False
            else:
                c = True

    return c
```

Lucky this is not [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)...
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHBboMwDIbveQofW6mVxnpqJa57gt1QVEVgaCQIyHFQeXqWhDIajeNy@mN//n9HGSZ@9OYyz7obemIgZaq@E6LCGiyTYmymQ6ss3wmta9kebwL8YZoWEQ4hOzKQcCc4xj4@Sxz4L1vIQMScUDiUjggN30fVOjx5bE0aIYfrNcrOy8@oGq@@yWG81D2BBm3C0BYUkAb8c0AXmfwtR6HrwEKeQyG3ifLdFFuLW2sZKM6Z9F7RtNmaLyB5QfAeU2SN@FLeOumkWbvr7GN7qeueHxLO0P3TCuLt60oh5vkH)

Comment: Thanks for your submission! I'd rather you didn't use globals, just in case, so you could consider returning `res, num` from `strategy` and writing `turn` as `turn(current_value, res, num)` please :)

Comment: Ok, edit in progress.

Comment: @jumbot Is this correct? When I tried it out with a fake strategy return, the args was a List of tuples, so I had to always chose the 0th tuple.

Comment: Should I make a github pull request?

Comment: If you think there's an error, please do

Comment: Ah. I'll add it myself, but if I've added it wrong do feel free to PR it.

Comment: @jumbot Ok, thanks

Comment: @jumbot run a few rounds and tell us the result please

Comment: @math Your submission lacks a case for `last_results` being empty and errors.

Comment: Really? I think I've done it right. I'm just returning last_results in a tuple right?

Comment: @jumbot Think this should work. But the tio link is wrong.

Comment: @math apologies, I may have copied an older version

Comment: @jumbot made my final edit.

Comment: You can discuss in the [chatbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122853/discussion-between-wasif-and-jumbot), comments should not run long discussions

Comment: Agreed, we can continue in the linked chatbox @math

Comment: This currently returns `None` in the first round (which confuses the controller as it's a falsey value). If you unindent the `return` statement it should work

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks, was a indent-o.

Comment: This new format highlights an error in this bot's algorithm, which I did not fix.  Feel free to fix it, @math.

Comment: @Spitemaster Aside from the "constant" bots, I'd suggest against updating the legacy versions. The controller can handle them fine, and you might miss some of the subtleties in the original bot

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I know, but this bot is literally half of the runtime (roughly 18s vs 14s for the rest of the bots put together).  I suppose it's not my call, though.

Comment: @jumbot It's your call.

Comment: @Spitemaster is its high runtime due to the fact that it's a legacy version?

Comment: @jumbot Yes.  `turn` is called many more times than `strategy`, and it runs through the entire list of past moves every time.

Comment: @math looking at this, that first loop is really inefficient. You should replace the contents of it with `if not i[1]: g = False` and then `break`.

Comment: @Spitemaster ah, indeed. And then as just mentioned, `turn` itself is grossly inefficient. In that case, please do update it to the new version. But don't change how it works if possible.

Comment: @jumbot is that what you meant?

Comment: @math no, I meant the _contents_ of the loop should be that

Comment: @math I've proposed a change updating it to the new version of the controller.  There's an obvious bug which I haven't fixed - I didn't want to change the functionality at all.

Comment: Ok, now I changed both the formats.

Comment: @Spitemaster What's that bug again?

Comment: @math If your opponent plays 1 or 2, it returns 100.  It probably should be returning 1 in that case.

Answer (score 5):

## Shortcut

Updated to use the new format (slight performance gain, which adds up):

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    return 50
```

Original:

```py
def strategy(last_results):
    return ()

def turn(current_value, *args):
    return current_value != 50
```

Not the patient type. Takes the reward of 100 on turn 50, instead of being a team player and getting taken advantage of down the line. Shortcut has some trust issues.

I'll start on a more complicated bot soon.

Comment: Nice! Surprisingly successful.

Comment: Nearly same logic as my bot though, +1.....

Answer (score 4):

## FunnyNumber

```python
def strategy(last_results):
	if len(last_results) > 420:
		return last_results[420][0]
	return 69
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TaG4pCixJDW9UiMnsbgkvii1uDSnpFjTioszM00hJzUPVVjBTsHEyAAoyVmUWlJalKeALBsNlIqNNojlgkmaWf7/DwA)

Like the joke itself, this bot is very uncreative. If there has been more than 420 rounds, FunnyNumber returns the result of the 420th (0-indexed) round. Otherwise, it counts up to 69 to try to earn 138 points.

Interestingly, this isn't the worse bot. Running a couple of arenas locally with this as a contestant, FunnyNumber gets 3/6 wins

Comment: Honestly, I was quite surprised to see your username in the corner instead of Lyxal's.

Comment: @user I wanted to snipe Lyxal from doing this more than I dislike this meme

Comment: I doubt Lyxal would have done that anyway. You've become your own enemy, caird, *worse* than your enemy, in fact. I'm ashamed of you. :P

Comment: You became the very thing you swore to destroy!

Comment: Your programme is incorrect. It should be `[0]` instead of `[1]`, since the second item in the tuple is whether the game was won or not, and is a bool rather than an int.

Answer (score 4):

## Zoidberg

```python
def strategy(_):
        return 48
```

Zoidberg is like a crab, but different. Credit to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) for [the original idea](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57613061#57613061).

I brute forced what number provides an optimal score with this approach. Surprisingly, this is better overall than Crab. Running locally I get

| Bot | Score | Wins | Overall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Crab | 12th | 1st | 6th |
| Zoidberg | 5th | 5th | 5th |

Answer (score 4):

## High to Low

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    if last_results:
        losses = [r[0] for r in last_results if not r[1]]
        if losses:
            return max(1, min(losses)-len(losses))
        num_of_rounds = len(last_results)
        if num_of_rounds>15 and len(losses)/num_of_rounds>0.6:
            return 1
    return 98
```

This bot always counts to `98` unless it has lost a round. Once this bot loses a round, it only counts to numbers lower than its lowest loss. If it has lost more than `60%` of the rounds, it plays `1`.

**Edit:** Changed the algorithm for calculating the number the bot should count to after losing from `max(1, min(losses)-1-len(losses))` to `max(1, min(losses)-len(losses))`. Hopefully, this should allow the bot to capitalize on static bots because it now counts to `1` below and not `2` below.

Comment: This is almost a contender for first place with Low Blow... nice one

Answer (score 3):

## Copycat

```python
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import random
contents = urllib.request.urlopen("https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223202/cooperative-counting").read()
html = bs.BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')

answers = html.findAll('div', {"class": "answer"})

strategies = []
for answer in answers:
    code = answer.find('div', {"class": "answercell"}).findAll('code')
    for any in code:
        strategies.append(str(any.contents[0]))

def newStrat(badOne = None):
    if not badOne == None: strategies.remove(badOne)
    return random.choice(strategies)
pick = newStrat()

def strategy(games):
    global pick
    try:
        exec(pick.replace('strategy','strategycopy'),globals())
        return strategycopy(games)
    except:
        pick = newStrat(pick)
        return strategy(games)
```

I didn't really feel like making a strategy up, so this bot will just copy someone elses answer.

Comment: I think this is off-topic, but I did make this answer specifically for this post

Comment: Do you think the question is off topic or your answer? The former isn’t, but if it’s the latter, I feel you should have asked about it first. I don’t know if it’s valid, but you can ask the OP or in the Nineteenth Byte, the site’s main chat room. And welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: @jumbot what do you think?

Comment: @Max I didn't have a rule against copying other people's submissions, I guess, so I'll have to accept this. But note that only one strategy will be picked for the entire tournament - i.e. while `strategy` is run many times, `pick` will only be set once when I import the file, so you may want to think about whether that's what you want.

Comment: I could easily change it to choose a random strategy each time, but I'm feeling lucky!!

Comment: This might violate either [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/66833) or [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1085/66833) standard loophole

Comment: Additionally, this breaks the controller if the bot it copies is a legacy version

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing those standard loopholes seem to be more applicable to code golf than KOTH, so I don't think they matter in this case. True about the legacy version breakage though.

Comment: @jumbot Most of the standard loopholes (barring ones such as the zero-length quine) are universal, unless specifically allowed by the challenge author (i.e. if you say they're good, they're good) :)

Comment: What happens if it tries to copy itself?

Comment: not sure. It should just hit the loop limit and choose a different strategy

Answer (score 3):

## Meandian

```python
import random
import statistics as stats
def strategy(last_results):
    def clamp(minimum, x, maximum):
        return max(minimum, min(x, maximum))
    last_results = sorted(map(lambda a: a[0], filter(lambda a: not a[1], last_results)))
    if not len(last_results):
        return random.randint(1,47)
    else:
        mean = round(stats.mean(last_results))
        median = round(stats.median(last_results))
    if mean == median:
        return mean
    elif mean > median:
        return clamp(1, median - random.randint(1,mean - median), 100)
    else: 
        return clamp(1, mean - random.randint(1,median - mean), 100)
```

This bot calculates the mean and median, and uses those calculations to predict a range of values that will be less than the other bot's choice, and will randomly choose one of them. It is also designed to be difficult to hardcode a solution to beat it but still handle other bots robustly.

edit: Meandian now only considers the round where the other bot wins during calculations to prevent itself from driving down itself unnessecarily.

Comment: Your last change broke it - line 10 now gives `statistics.StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point`.  You need to make sure that filter doesn't filter everything out.

Comment: @Spitemaster I moved the filter before the length check so it should be fixed now.

Comment: Now you filter it twice, and the second time breaks.  Take that out and it's all good

Comment: @Spitemaster Oops- I meant `ctrl x` not `ctrl c`. Should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

### Tit for tat

```
def strategy(last_results):
    return last_results[-1][0] if last_results else 100
```

Very basic strategy.

Comment: Should be `last_results[-1][0]` if you just want to return the value that won last round.

Comment: @Spitemaster Thanks, it was late at night and I wasn't thinking correctly.

Answer (score 3):

## The diff predictor

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    previous_values = list()
    diffs = list()
    for num,result in last_results:
        if result:
            oppo_play = min(100,num+1)
        else:
            oppo_play = num
        if len(previous_values)>0:
            diffs.append(oppo_play-previous_values[-1])
        previous_values.append(oppo_play)

    if len(previous_values) == 0:
        move = 100
    elif len(previous_values) == 1:
        move = previous_values[0]
    else:
        diffs = diffs[-10:]
        if len(diffs)>2:
            # remove outliers
            diffs.remove(min(diffs))
            diffs.remove(max(diffs))
        meandiff = sum(diffs)/len(diffs)
        move = previous_values[-1] + meandiff -1

    if move==99 and len(last_results)<950:
        # Let's be nice (for a while)
        move=100
    return min(100, max(1, round(move)))
```

Predicts what the opponent will play next based on the average difference between consecutive previous plays (discarding highest and lowest, to avoid being fooled by FunnyNumber). Assumes the opponent played N+1 whenever it wins with N.

It plays 100 as long as the opponent does the same, until towards the last games, where it decides there's no use in being nice anymore.

Answer (score 3):

## Lumberjack

The plan is get to a winning position and then head towards 1 faster than the opponent can recover. Partly inspired by other bots here!

```
def strategy(last_results):
    round_number = len(last_results)
    if round_number == 0:
        return 100
    if all(i == (1, False) for i in last_results):
        return 1  # lumberjacks don't like crabs
    score, success = last_results[-1]
    if round_number == 1:
        if success and score == 100:
            return 100
        return max(1, score/2)
    old_score, old_success = last_results[-2]
    if success and old_success:  # won previous two rounds
        if score == 100:
            return 97  # try and get in under fair bots
        else:
            # minimal pruning, light regrowth
            return max(1, (score+old_score)*0.4 + 15)
    if not success:
        if not old_success:
            # heavy pruning
            return max(1, score*0.5)
            # light pruning
        return max(1, score*0.75)
    else:
        # regrow by small amounts
        return min(100, score + old_score*0.2 + 10)
```

I dreamt this up on Thursday, but I wasn't able to write it down and experiment until today. It's a late entry so I'm not expecting any prizes.

Comment: Did I submit after the deadline? Oh no :'(

Comment: You're about one hour late... sorry. I can run it though and let you know how it would do :)

Comment: @jumbot that awfully kind of you, thanks!

Comment: Lumberjack comes 8th overall, 13th on score, and 8th on wins... not bad!

Answer (score 2):

## The Desperate Fighter

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 285 bytes

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    if len(last_results) == 0:
      return True,
    pos = last_results[-1][0]
    if pos in [49,50]:
      return False,
    if pos in list(range(10,21)):
      return False,
    else:
      return True,

def turn(current_value, *args):
    return args[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/dCsIwDIXv9xS57GRC58@FQm99Au/GGEWzOSjdSFNhT19bdeBvrpKc8yWcceLLYNchnLEFx6QZu0kY7bghdN6wy/cZxBoHBwpehWpZ1pWs72rfgkH7zoFSIB8wACF7snAkj8VMpJO9hWqzK7ay/nAetHFfVtM7FqRth6KUxarM8/8Uxu7n9yxFTbM4eSK03Fy1iQIsNHVz3CeRNjFjCDc)

This bot will try to win in anyways it can....

## Bot handling

- Lyxal: I stop at 50 to attack his bot
- math: I stop at 10 to 20 for defence to his bot
- Redwolf: I stop at 49 to attack his bot

Comment: Your programme lacks a case for `last_results` being empty...

Comment: Also, I think you slightly misunderstand how this works - `strategy` should return the `args` that you want passed to `turn`, not call `turn` directly itself. Oh, and thanks for the submission btw :)

Comment: @jumbot That means turn() would call stragety()? (ADDed empty tuple check)

Comment: No, neither calls either. The controller calls them.

Comment: @jumbot is it ok now

Comment: also, `last_results` contains the results of previous rounds (i.e. full sequences counted). So if you lose your first round because your opponent stops counting at, say, 80, `last_results` will look like: `[(80, False)]` - `80` because that was the last value, `False` because you lost.

Comment: @jumbot so that last_results is a list not tuple?

Comment: um, it technically works now I think, but it's not doing what you want it to do... see the edit I made to the 'Technical details' section in the main post. There is an example of what `last_results` does and what it will look like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122853/discussion-between-wasif-and-jumbot).

Answer (score 2):

## Naughty or Nice?

```python
def strategy(last_results):
        scores = list(map(lambda a: a[0], last_results))

        if all(score == 100 for score in scores):
                if len(scores) == 999:
                        return 98
                return 100

        constant_bots = {
                69: 68,
                68: 67,
                50: 49,
                48: 47
        }

        return constant_bots.get(scores[-1], 1)
```

Naughty or Nice? works on a very simple premise: Every match, one bot must be Naughty.

- If the opponent counts to 100, Naughty or Nice? considers it "nice", and so Naughty or Nice? must be Naughty. It counts up to 100 with its opponent until it reaches the final round, where it stops at 98
- Otherwise, the other bot is Naughty, and so doesn't deserve any points. In this case, either:

  - The opponent is a "constant" bot (FunnyNumber, Zoidberg, Shortcut), so we return 1 less than them
  - The opponent is not a constant bot, so we throw a tantrum and play 1 for the rest of the match

Answer (score 1):

## Hard-coded

```python
import random
def strategy(last_results):
  if len(last_results) == 0:
    return 65
  if last_results[-1][0] in [50,49]:
    return 49 # Shortcut detected, attack!
  if last_results[-1][0] in [69,65]:
    return 65 # FunnyNumber detected, attack!
  if last_results[-1][0]==1:
    return 1 # Crab detected, defend!
  else:
    return random.randint(1,100) # give away, my mind is boggling with numbers
```

It is mainly designed to compete against caird and Redwolf and user

Answer (score 1):

## Hawk

A quick internet search reveals hawks eat pythons >:).

This strategy takes the average, weighted a bit, of the winning scores and returns its floor, or 47 at the beginning. Purely functional and not python >:).

---

A Pure Python version (untested), courtesy of caird coinheringaahing:

```python
def strategy(last_results):
  if not last_results:
    return 47
  return max(1, min(50, sum(map(lambda t: t[0], last_results)) // (len(last_results)*1.5)))
```

---

### In [Hy](http://hylang.org/)

```
(defn strategy [last-results]
  (if last-results
    (max 1 (min 50
      (// (reduce +
           (map (fn[t] (get t 0)) last-results))
         (* 1.5 (len last-results)))))
    47))
```

Comment: A [pure Python version](https://tio.run/##VY27CoAwEARr8xVXJiAoiI2/IiIRzwckUXKbwq@PNoJ2w8Dsnhe2IzQ5z7yQIFrwemlnBWNkSQ5iOlXsC4UD9NWPLSIjxUBtrV6U5LW35zPgp9kSOkJfD@WvNIaqihyH/03ONw) by my understanding

Comment: sorry I can't view TIO. You can edit it in if you want.

Comment: [This breaks the controller, at least on my local copy, but I'm working on it](https://github.com/jthistle/KOTH-counting/issues/2)

Comment: @Wezl Hi, I've suggested an edit to put the Python code above the Hy code. That way the auto-update script will consider the Python code instead of the Hy code. Thanks for the submission!

Comment: I've rolled back the edit, that'll break the autoscript, as it will find the Hy answer as the first code block. There's no way to hide multiline code blocks in spoilers, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

## Grim Trigger

```python
def strategy(last_results):
    if any([not r[1] for r in last_results]):
        return 1
    else:
        return 100
```

This bot prefers to cooperate and count to `100`, but if the opponent tries to troll it, it pulls the trigger and only counts to `1` for the rest of the round.